# Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular7

I have upgraded our project to angular 7 and everything works perfectly. However, when I do ng serve --aot or build the product version with aot = true, I get the following run time error:

```
error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
at constructTimingAst (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2316:15)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitAnimate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2025:25)
at visitDslNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:1759:28)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2003:61
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitSequence (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2003:35)
at visitDslNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:1755:28)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitQuery (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2235:25)
at visitDslNode (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:1771:28)
at http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:2003:61
```

Any thoughts.

Comment: It might be useful if you tell us which version you upgraded from.

Comment: of course- from angular 5 to 7.